ModalBottomSheet Intercepts when LazyColumn Scrolling Stops
I have a simple LazyColumn in a ModalBottomSheet. The issue is that when the LazyColumn scrolling comes to a stop the ModalBottomsSheet briefly takes scroll control for a second before LazyColumn regains control. The bottom sheet should only be draggable on the handle or when scrolling reaches the top.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SheetTest() {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
            skipPartiallyExpanded = true,
            confirmValueChange = { it != SheetValue.Hidden } // Disabled dismiss for testing
        ),
        onDismissRequest = {},
        containerColor = Color.Blue
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(
                items = dummyPlaces // Random strings
            ) { text ->
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    fontSize = 48.sp,
                    color = Color.Green
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm still a new at Compose but was wondering if there's way to fix this using NestedScrollConnection? I've tried nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()) but that wasn't useful.
I'm just surprised that nobody's asked about this considering how common this Composable setup is, or I just suck at finding answers. But any help would be appreciated! Here's a video demo - this is not a great user experience.

Have you managed to solve this problem? Have you tried using ModalBottomSheetLayout from material?

I haven't. Nor have I tried a newer Compose version but apparently this is still an issue - you can see this in the Compose Material Catalog app. ModalBottomSheetLayout might have the same issue, but it's not applicate to my case.
